# Why does color prompt is not working when using "su -"

Tags: bash, shell, root, prompt, su

I'm using ~/.bashrc files to add color and special scripts to the shell prompt.
I'm getting the colors and aliases when in normal user or su but not when i'm doing su -

Here are some screenshots that should help explaining this :

- As normal user or as root with `su`:

[image: As normal user and as root (using su)]

- As root with `su -`:

[image: As root (using su-)]

What do i need to do in order to have the colors and all my extra stuff when typing "su -" ?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: the root shell should work faster, and be less error-prone, so it's probable that as root a different shell opens, with less color capabilities. see [different shell for root and non root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/different-shell-for-root-and-non-root-user) on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

with

> su -

you became the user with all enviroment's variables, and probably root hasn't any color set.
copy .bashrc of your user into root home folder (usually /root)

Comment: root has the same .bashrc file as the normal user
http://imgur.com/a/zBPxR

Comment: `su -` tells `su` to start a login shell, which does not read `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   -, -l, --login
>          make  the shell a login shell, clears all envvars except for TERM, initializes
>          HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME and PATH
> ```

Try "-m" option. As the manual says:

> ```
>    -m, --preserve-environment
>          do not reset HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME environment variables
> ```

Comment: If i use -m it'll not be the same as using su - 
I really need to login just using su -

Answer (score 2):

I did that : `cp /root/.bashrc /etc/profile`
and now when i use : `su -` i get the colored prompt, aliases etc..

Thanks you guys for the help